# Why are selectors missing from Wordpress core data store

Tags: javascript, wordpress, core-data, wordpress-gutenberg

When selecting the "core" store of Wordpress JavaScript API via `wp.data.select("core")` I get an incomplete list of selectors.

> The selector I get are the following: 
>   canUser: ƒ () 
>   getAuthors: ƒ ()
>   getEmbedPreview: ƒ () 
>   getEntitiesByKind: ƒ () 
>   getEntity: ƒ ()
>   getEntityRecord: ƒ () 
>   getEntityRecords: ƒ () 
>   getMedia: ƒ ()
>   getMediaItems: ƒ () 
>   getPostType: ƒ () 
>   getPostTypes: ƒ ()
>   getTaxonomies: ƒ () 
>   getTaxonomy: ƒ () 
>   getThemeSupports: ƒ ()
>   getUserQueryResults: ƒ ()
>   hasUploadPermissions: ƒ ()
>   isPreviewEmbedFallback: ƒ () 
>   isRequestingEmbedPreview: ƒ ()

Instead of the full lists shown in https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core/

For example, `wp.data.select("core").getCurrentUser()` returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Because these were added in @wordpress/core-data 2.3.0 and WordPress currently only includes release 2.2.2 of that package. See the [trac ticket #47843](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47843) for details